# Generate Info (wrapper) Class from stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, class, dotnetnuke, wrapper, codesmith

I am in a crucial project and I am trying to speed up the development phase by  using codesmith for generating the business class DAL and info class for the tables of my project.

There are about 50 tables with relationships parent child many to many and for retrieving data I have to code several inner joins in stored procedures.
I have to combine fields from many tables and this makes working with the info class difficult.

Is there anyway to generate info class from stored procedures or to be more exact is there a way to parse the result set of the stored procedure and to generate the info class with properties for every column in that result set.

Please if anyone can give me some advice and tell me how to achieve this.
Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily generate code using templates based on stored procs which are exposed via the SchemaExplorer.CommandSchema collection. Somebody has written a helpful blog post about how to get started - http://jiangningtang.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!90A00B80F75CB859!210.entry.

Answer (score 0):

One trick I used to do - and I dont use CodeSmith anymore - was to make a view or fake table with the fields I want in the info class. Point CodeSmith at it and generate a class from that.

Another way to sort of get by is to avoid the info class and some of the custom business objects and build you own data layer - sometimes in complex projects this is easier.

Answer (score 0):

I have another suggestion, Create a class library and add a DataSet (Typed Data set available in Data section or add new item) to it, drop all your SPs and tables in the data context and copy the cs code from designer ;)

i hope this will help you.